# Testing native, sponsored banner ads on Stack Overflow (updated August 14)

Tags: discussion, design, advertising, announcement

**UPDATE:** We have concluded our tests of the native banner ads on Stack Overflow on July 20th, 2023. With your feedback on this post and the ads’ performance metrics, we have gathered sufficient information that will guide us to develop different ad formats or new products you hopefully will find helpful. Thank you all for the time, patience, and feedback offered.

---

While we are testing banner ad variations, we decided to add one more design variation to see how it performs. This variation has no logo and a gray background color. We’ve also moved the ad designation (“Ad by Audiobubble”) into the ad box, as was suggested in the original feedback.

All of the same guarantees listed in the original post continue to apply (e.g. testing dates, ad placement, clear identification that it’s an ad, etc.)

**Here's what the new design looks like:**

Light mode:

[image: Screenshot of a question page using the light theme, showing a banner ad in the newest style being tested]

Dark mode:

[image: Screenshot of a question page using dark mode, showing a banner ad in the newest style being tested]

---

### Original post:

We will be conducting a trial for a new ad format on Stack Overflow. The trial will start on **July 6** and will run for approximately 3 weeks. The ads will be running worldwide and visible to all users.

**These ads will be shown in the same placements you currently see banner ads, and are not an additional ad** being added to question pages. (In other words, the existing banner ads in these locations will, for the duration of the trial, some times be replaced with this new type of ad. The existing banner ads are provided by a client, need to abide by our ad guidelines, and undergo an internal approval process, but their designs can vary drastically from one ad to another. The ads with the format being tested will have a more consistent, unified theme.) These ads will also be subject to the [reduced ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) user setting, as this setting is tied to the ad slot, and not the ad type.

They will take some cues from the site's style, but are still clearly marked as being ads:

- They'll have a "Ad by COMPANY" on the ads' top left corner;
- They'll have a "Report this ad" link on the ads' bottom right corner;
- The ads' call-to-action button will *never* feature a prompt in the form of "ask," "answer," or anything along those lines that could lead users to think they'd be interacting with the site's main experience when in fact they'd be interacting with an ad.

**Here's what they'll look like:**

Light mode:
[image: Screenshot of a question page using the light theme, showing a banner ad in the new style being tested]

Dark mode:
[image: Screenshot of a question page using dark mode, showing a banner ad in the new style being tested]

Please note that the current iteration of this project has already been built as of this announcement. Therefore, it is probably too late to change anything for the upcoming trial. *However*, **we are still interested in getting your feedback (as an answer below)!** During the trial period, we'll be monitoring the new format's performance, as well as any bug reports and other feedback about the design that we get from the community.

Once this trial is over, we'll be determining the next steps based on y'all's feedback, as well as the new format's performance (including any reports of user feedback). Any feedback provided now will be weighed in potential future revisions of the native banner ad format. Whether we decide to keep the new format or retire it, we'll keep you looped into what our thinking on next steps is.

Comment: Again? Not asking for feedback? *"Please note that the current iteration of this project is already built as of this announcement"*, no wonder why the strike is stil going. Keep up the good work.... And please tag accordingly, there is no [[tag:discussion]], it's just another [[tag:announcement]].

Comment: Wow. That looks extremely annoying.

Comment: Why have you blurred so much text in the screenshot? Did some of the HMP/featured posts happen to be about the strike?

Comment: @0stone0 This new format is not being rolled out as a full feature at this point, as the post highlights, and will be undergoing a trial period. For that reason, we _are_ asking for feedback — that's what this question's doing. As such, the tagging also feels appropriate to me (additionally, there _are_ a group of mandatory tags, of which [announcement] is not a part).

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype It's not uncommon to blur parts of an image when showing a preview of something, to ensure the focus is kept on the bits we're announcing, and not on, say, a user avatar ;)

Comment: Can't wait to update my 'uBlock' [Filter](/a/416973) (already handling the annoying Red Dot for the Review Queues + Sticky Navigbar)…! Oh!, I had to disable 'uBlock (Origine)' to be able to see [one of the current Ads](https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/18192076905603456239) (about "Stack Overflow for Teams") which was already "naturally" blocked because of the `googlesyndication.com` URL… Will the "new" Ads also be hosted on that same Domain, or on some "internal" SO/SE Server…? // The "Report this ad" Link is also already outside the Block, and it's clear that it belongs to the Ad

Comment: Same domain, @chivracq

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of the ad placement on a closed and locked question? I have concerns the ad will look too similar to post notices.

Comment: can't wait for my adblocker to update. I know you have to make money to maintain the company but really ? ad like that is so 2000-2010. found something else. no one like ad.

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype I will list the articles they tried to blur:

**Overflow Blog:**

>How Bloomberg’s engineers built a culture of knowledge sharing

>Making computer science more humane at Carnegie Mellon (ep. 585)

**Featured:**

>Starting the Prompt Design Site: A New Home in our Stack Exchange Neighborhood

>Colors update: A more detailed look 

>Unreadable :(

>Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned 

**Hot Meta Posts:**

>Moderation strike: how is the discussion going between the moderators and Stack Overflow, Inc?

>Unreadable :(

Comment: I laugh, because I use Firefox w/ AdBlocker Ultimate, and I've never seen an SO ad in my life...

Comment: @0stone0 As much as I don't like ads, let's be real. No company (of a significant size) will ever asks its users for a *permission* to make money with ads.

Comment: I personally hate the placement and design of these ads, but thanks for engaging and patiently addressing objective feedback @JNat. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for actively engaging with the people posting answers.

Comment: I hope this makes ads on the site less annoying. I think that'd be great!

Comment: Wait, are these _native_ ads? As in, served wholly from SO-owned domains? (I don't mean in the usual sense of "looks like a question or answer".)

Comment: The images in this post could do with some [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/176887) to highlight the banners.

Comment: These are still served through Google Ad Manager, much like most of our other ads, @wizzwizz4 — the native here refers solely to the styling of the ads.

Answer (score 98):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The design has been changed to have a white background instead, for the duration of the trial. This option might blend too much into the background, but at least doesn't cause a clash with post notice banners. In future iterations, we may explore other options.

---

**The blue background is not an appropriate design for advertisements.** The Stacks design system calls these ["Notices"](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/), which "deliver System or Engagement messaging, informing the user about product or account statuses and related actions". Advertisements about unrelated products do not provide information about *this* product (Q&A) and so should not be displayed as if they were [informational notices inserted within the content area](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/#inline).

Practically speaking, these ads will look too much like the "locked", "protected", and "closed" notices which are displayed by the system as blue banners above the post.

You need to pick a different style. Frankly, I'd urge you to pick a different style **before the trial starts**. I realize that the infrastructure has already been built and changes are meant to be deferred, but this is a minor change to the styling. And it is a *critical* one.

Blending in with the page's normal content is *not a good thing* for banner ads. Not for us, and not for the advertiser.

I'd recommend the classic black border with a white interior. Failing that, perhaps [the "default"](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/#filled) or [the "inverted"](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/#filled-important) styles would be acceptable, given that they are more neutral colors. Neither gray nor black are already used by the system for informational notices or warnings.

Comment: Lemme see what can be done about this. I'd noticed these would prolly clash late last week too, and we were already talking about how to address this.

Comment: Awesome, @JNat; thanks for following up on this! I agree that the white background may not be the ideal solution, either, but at least it's better than blue. I really appreciate you shepherding this through before the launch.

Answer (score 85):

Aren't these only more effective because they're inherently deceptive by taking on the design of the site and looking like any other feature of the site?

In the end, they're still ads with a sole purpose of fooling users into reading/clicking on them. They aren't there to surface useful information or something that the user might want, they're there to serve a paying partner who want's their product marketed. They'll always be this, whether they're suggesting learning courses or magic AI solutions looking for a problem.

At minimum, though, could we avoid making them look like a banner meant to convey important information? I know that would inherently be more effective than an ad that looks like an ad, but if now we're gonna deal with ad blindness by turning to ads that look like important information banners... what are we going to do to make actually important information banners stand out?

Comment: I would really like to see some more specific visual cues indicating that this is an ad rather than just "Promoted by *X*" above the box to cut down on this exact thing. I don't think it _has_ to be "inherently deceptive" per say, but to avoid that it definitely needs to be labelled accordingly.

Comment: Not sure about the feasibility of this solution, but would something like a tooltip that explains more in detail what "Promoted by _X_" means accomplish that effect, @zcoop98? Did you have any thoughts on what "more specific visual cues" we could test?

Comment: Would an indication more in the lines of "Paid advertisement from _X_" be a clearer label, for instance?

Comment: Simply "Ad by AudioBubble" or "Advertisement by AudioBubble" would be clearer, too, I think, @JNat, and shorter. "Promoted" just has too many meanings, whereas "advertisement" is pretty obvious. 0stone0's feedback that these buttons should be *inside* the box, not outside of it, also makes sense to me. And I really dislike the blue background color, as that looks like an "informational" banner that the site is displaying to me (and *does* display in many cases) about how to properly use the site, some new feature, or whatever. Ads don't generally look like this.

Comment: Please have a look at the new screenshots — we've made changes to the design so these don't clash with post notification banners.

Answer (score 66):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> The wording has been changed to "Ad by COMPANY" instead.

---

“Promoted by $company” is not appropriate wording. It implies content authored by Stack Exchange that is being sponsored by someone. “Paid advertisement from $company” would make it clear that the block below is an advertisement paid for and provided by a third party.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We're discussing alternative option internally, as per the discussion in the comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425384/testing-native-sponsored-banner-ads-on-stack-overflow-starting-july-6/425422#comment963819_425385) and your feedback ^_^

Answer (score 53):

1. *'Promoted by'* and *'Report this ad'* buttons should be **inside** the box, seems like the question itself is promoted by that company, not the ad
2. Please rethink the width/alignment, the ad shouldn't be wider than the question/user-box

Comment: While I understand your concern on 1., I'm also afraid that moving the "promoted by" to inside the box might make it _less_ visible. "Report this ad" is outside of it as it is on any other ad, I believe. Regardless, your feedback was noted and will be kept in mind when we evaluate next steps ^_^

Answer (score 27):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> This information has been added to the question body, for visibility.

---

Will these still be subject to the “disable ads” setting available to high-rep users, or no?

Comment: Where is this setting?

Comment: These will be subject to the same setting, yes.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads), @holydragon

Answer (score 8):

As someone who has whitelisted Stack Overflow (the network) from ad blockers, I really hope this change can improve the user experience. I'll try to comment based on my experience with current ads.

- One thing that I hope it can be improved is **the loading speed**. With my poor internet connection, current leaderboard ads were often loaded late, and thus pushed the page a little bit down later. On a certain situation, this has even made me accidentally click *the spam link* instead of the flag button :(
- As for the content, while I'm probably fortunate not having seen such inappropiate/intrusive ads (perhaps they don't target my country? :), I also hope that this change may improve the following issues:

  - [Why is Stack Overflow trying to start audio?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331960/241919)
  - [Stop with the Sex Ads on SE sites, ESPECIALLY sites like "The Workplace"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334537/241919)
  - [Ads on SE sites are excessively animated, irrelevant, dubious and resource-intensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329547/241919)

  Heck, if this change actually fixes these issues, then I hope this style can also be applied to sidebar ads!
- As for the design, I don't really have anything to add, so I'll defer to other answers for that.

Comment: Slightly controversial view - but these and other purely text ads are the *least* evil option as far as ads go.  And that's what the sidebar ads *used* to be - so moving to all text ads would probably the best alternative as far as non annoyance goes

Comment: Load time should be similar, I'm told.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen a similar anti-pattern on twitter, though 'worse' in many ways. Twitter's ads tend to 'hide' inside post threads.

- As an adblock user, will these ads be blocked by adblock 'cleanly' or go through. I've less of a problem seeing those than, well adverse interactions with adblock and finding big ugly gaps in my pages.
- One of the previous issues with 'new' ad formats was they slipped through the quality guidelines. Its probably worth considering how and who clears these ads to avoid embarassment, though I guess you can't get as [bad as this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334537/stop-with-the-sex-ads-on-se-sites-especially-sites-like-the-workplace)
- As a Moderator on a smaller site, the question of if we'll get these ads and if they will be tailored to the site comes to mind, but that's a problem for future me (and you)
- With other ads of this nature, in addition to a "report this ad", a "I'm not interested in this ad" would be nice. It feels like a common pattern where I'm getting organic ads, and it improves the experience of ads my adblocker can't quite deal with.

Comment: I know folks are paying close attention to the guidelines, so I don't expect mishaps on that front — if you see any, though, please report the ad. For now the ads are SO only, but I'm sure the relevance of them for other sites if we end up rolling them out to the network will be subject to the same requirements we currently have for other ad types. Will keep the feedback for the "not interested" for future iterations (not sure we can squeeze that in at this point), and lemme check on the adblock question.

Comment: Just got confirmation that the ads' behavior as it pertains to ad blockers should be the same as it is with the current ads.

Answer (score 1):

I voted it up.  105 downvotes (well, 104 now that I voted it up), really?  This site is a valuable resource, and running a web site costs money which has to come from somewhere.  They're not even increasing the number of ads, just changing the appearance of ads in locations they already were.  They're not obnoxious ads that make noise (the only ones I ever ad blocked), animated, or pop-up ads.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: Just FYI, [the vote breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) is currently +38/-141.

Comment: SO users are ... touchy ... see the latest drama over a minor adjustment to the voting buttons

Answer (score -1):

> We will be conducting a trial for a new ad format on Stack Overflow.

I can still block the ads with [AdBlocker Ultimate](https://adblockultimate.net/), right?

Comment: See [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425384/testing-native-sponsored-banner-ads-on-stack-overflow-starting-july-6#comment964379_425433) –  the ads' behavior as it pertains to ad blockers should be the same as it is with the current ads.