# Is the "Privilege: reduce ads" page outdated?

Tags: bug, privileges

On the Stack Overflow [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), it says that at a reputation of 200, the user gets a reduction of ads. On [the page describing it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads), it shows this image, with the red boxes showing where the ads that would be removed would be.

[image]

The layout of Stack Overflow has been changed quite a bit since this screenshot. Nonetheless, I cannot see the ads that these boxes are referring to. My account has a reputation of 66, and for multiple questions the webpage looks like this.

[image]

I am pretty sure that I am not running any adblockers.

Is everyone experiencing this? Is this privilege deprecated? Or the screenshots are simply outdated?

Comment: Yea, that seems pretty outdated. (Not deprecated)

Comment: The question "asked 15 hours ago" in that screenshot was [actually asked in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3865152/6083675).

Comment: While other aspects of this Help Center page may be outdated and need to be rewritten, I believe this style of ad still exists (see Andrew T.'s answer for an example).

Comment: @V2Blast but updating it with a new screenshot (after 13+ years) is not a bad idea :)

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ: Agreed. It's actually already on our radar to update it :)

Comment: @V2Blast [meta-tag:status-review]?

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ: Eh, I'll add it if the CM handling the updates wants me to – but overall, it seems like the bug report in this question isn't actually accurate, since this type of ad still seems to exist.

Comment: @V2Blast Agreed. [meta-tag:feature-request] would be better than [meta-tag:bug].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No, leaderboard style ads still exist.**

[image]

(Leaderboard style ad about Japanese Stack Overflow due to my browser's setting)

However, based on my experience, ads don't always appear, and *these ads are targeted*, thus if there are no ads that fit the criteria, then they won't be shown at all.

Comment: The [recent native banner ad experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425384) is further proof that these are indeed still around.